# Rendering an object at different locations with different rotations

Tags: rendering, scripting, modifiers

I need to render 1000-2000 images. There is 2 object in this scene. One of them should be in different positions each image and apply boolean to other object. How do I automotize this action Is there any script for this process

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried some nft generating techniques to produce images but none of them worked. Boolean modifier don't work with them

Comment: How to define the location and rotation of the object? random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the moving object, on frame 1 add a LocRot Keyframe, then in the graph editor select the 6 transform channels one by one and add 6 noise modifiers, one each, tweak the values to reach a random Loc and Rot into the desired action field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that will work